# How to import a function or a class outside django project to it?

Tags: python, django

I have a project with core module which contains my classes and function s and a rest API using django, I want to import core files inside django but I couldn't.
the project structure is the following:
app
  - core
     -manager
  - rest-api
     -api(django)

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I have resolved this problem by adding

```
import sys
```

`sys.path.append('path/to/root/project')`

before the import in each file